# How to try for/if loop method that adds Date to an Arraylist and compares it to Date that is already in Array list than throws NameDuplicateException

Tags: java

I have this

```
public interface AddMenu {
    void onMenuAdded (Menu menu) throws NameDuplicateException;
}
```

Than this exception;

```
public class NameDuplicateException extends Exception {
    public NameDuplicateException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

That is overriden in Restaurant class;

```
@Override
public void onMenuAdded(Menu menu) throws NameDuplicateException {
        this.getMenus().add
        throw new NameDuplicateException("Message");
    }
}
```

And main  that looks like this where I have to try a method that adds Date and compares it to another Date that has the same date, and catches NameDuplicateException;

```
public class zadatak17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Restaurant> restoraunts = new ArrayList();
        restoraunts.add(new Restaurant(12,23,"Tuzla", "BiH", 75000,1,"Sedra",5,new ArrayList<Menu>()));
        restoraunts.get(0).getMenus().add(new Menu(1,"menu1",1,new Date(2017,10,14)));
        restoraunts.get(0).getMenus().add(new Menu(2,"menu2",1,new Date(2017,6,15)));
        restoraunts.get(0).getMenus().add(new Menu(3,"menu3",1,new Date(2017,11,17)));
        restoraunts.add(new Restaurant(121,233,"Tuzla", "BiH", 75000,2,"Limenka",6,new ArrayList<Menu>()));
        restoraunts.get(1).getMenus().add(new Menu(1,"menu1",2,new Date(2017,6,14)));
        restoraunts.get(1).getMenus().add(new Menu(2,"menu2",2,new Date(2017,10,15)));
        restoraunts.get(1).getMenus().add(new Menu(3,"menu3",2,new Date(2017,11,17)));
        restoraunts.add(new Restaurant(1212,2331,"Tuzla", "BiH", 75000,3,"Sarajka",7,new ArrayList<Menu>()));
        restoraunts.get(2).getMenus().add(new Menu(1,"menu1",3,new Date(2017,6,14)));
        restoraunts.get(2).getMenus().add(new Menu(2,"menu2",3,new Date(2017,11,15)));
        restoraunts.get(2).getMenus().add(new Menu(3,"menu3",3,new Date(2017,10,17)));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I'm absolute begginer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two Date objects, you will need the `compareTo()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) from the Date class.

Then the for loop:

```
// looping through the restoraunts
for(Restaurant resto : restoraunts){
    // looping through the dates of the restaurant, given you have a getter for the Date object
    for(Date date : resto.getDate()){
        // now we have a date, let's compare it to all the other dates
        for(Restaurant resto_bis : restoraunts){
             for(Date date_bis : resto_bis.getDate()){
                 if (date_bis != date)
                     if (date.compateTo(date_bis) == 0) raise new NameDuplicateException()
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it does, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer ;). And if it doesn't, I can work through it with you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
@Override
public void onMenuAdded(Menu menu) throws NameDuplicateException {
  if(this.getMenus().contains(menu))
    throw new NameDuplicateException("Message");
  else
    this.getMenus().add(menu);
}
```

For this to work, you have to implement `hashcode()` and `equals()` methodes for your `Menu` class.

Comment: Actualy it has to add new date and compare it with one in Arraylist

Comment: Is there any chance you can answer me how to use this in main?